# Input function need to press enter several times to get value after wake up Python uiautomator

Tags: python, python-3.x, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to get something on Android phone using uiautomator, and if it cannot get it, I'll let user to manual input the value. However, the input() function is strange after uiautomator is called, user needs to press ENTER key once before input values. If two uiautomator are called, user needs to press ENTER key twice before input values.
Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks!

```py
import uiautomator
d = uiautomator.Device('serial number', 5555)
print(d.info)
in = input('Type something:')
print(in)
```

I expect to get user input values after press ENTER key once. However, user needs to press ENTER key before type something then press ENTER key again to pass input values to parameter in. The more uiautomator is called, the more ENTER key needs to be pressed before type something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is uiautomator bug and is no longer updated. uiautomator2 has fixed this.